# ArcGIS Pro Python package and SSL

Tags: python, arcgis-pro, conda, ssl

Our company internet gateway rejects Python package downloading as insecure but does work with `--insecure` in a conda call. This leaves non command line users stuck with the default ArcGIS Pro environment and prevents using the GUI to making clone and adding packages.

Is it possible to tell the ArcGIS Pro python package manager GUI to ignore SSL?

Elaboration:

- For security we cannot write to Program Files and therefore cannot make environments in there
- ArcGIS Pro can write new environments to user profiles but fails through the GUI
- Using conda we can clone the default environment to our user profiles but fails unless we use `--insecure` switch
- We are told our firewall SSL inspection rejects the connection when conda and pip try to verify SSL
- We can install with conda and pip to the new environment, the files and folders are in Lib\site-packages folder, but do not appear in the conda list

So I have 2 problems but the first

- it is not local permissions but inability to download that appears to cause failure to clone becaue clone involves downloading. If ArcGIS Pro could set SSL_NO_VERIFY=1 I assume users can just use the GUI to clone environments.
- If that works I could download new packages using the ArcGIS Pro GUI, theoretically ArcGIS Pro would recognise them, and they would work. The new conda environment downloads but does not recognise what is downloaded.

Comment: Using the "You break it, you buy it" principle, shouldn't this be on the IT staff to manage Python updates? Using `--insecure` for "security" seems quite daft.

Comment: It would be helpful to share the specific error message because the issue could be the client refusing to make the connection because of missing company-specific root certificates not in the default conda deployment.  I doubt the company network gateway is actively blocking HTTPS connections to a site but allowing HTTP connections.

Comment: Have you raised this with ESRI support? They may have a solution?

Comment: @Hornbydd I can talk my IT people more and suggest that and hope something eventually happens.